# Does an unpacked msgpack_object depend on the buffer from which it is unpacked?

Tags: c, msgpack

Based on the bizarre behaviour I'm seeing, I'm guessing that the following code is not valid.  My question is: does the msgpack_object created below depend on the msgpack_sbuffer?  That is, is the msgpack_object (in msg.data) invalid, once msgpack_sbuffer_free(buffer) is called?  If so, what's the correct way to get a heap allocated msgpack_object with no dependencies in this situation?

```
msgpack_object create_static_msg_object() {
  msgpack_sbuffer* buffer = msgpack_sbuffer_new();
  msgpack_packer* pk = msgpack_packer_new(buffer, msgpack_sbuffer_write);


  // does some calls to msgpack_pack_*() here

  msgpack_unpacked msg;
  msgpack_unpacked_init(&msg);

  msgpack_unpack_next(&msg, buffer->data, buffer->size, NULL);

  /* cleaning */
  msgpack_sbuffer_free(buffer);
  msgpack_packer_free(pk);

  return msg.data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*- Does the `msgpack_object` created below depend on the `msgpack_sbuffer`?*

No. Your `msgpack_sbuffer` is only used at packing time (it is the growing buffer used by `msgpack_packer` to write the binary serialization).

Instead the msgpack object depends on the `msgpack_unpacked` structure:

```
typedef struct msgpack_unpacked {
    msgpack_zone* zone;
    msgpack_object data;
} msgpack_unpacked;
```

The object is closely related to this structure, and the dynamic memory related to this object (e.g. if it contains arrays, maps, etc) is managed by `zone`.

*- Is the `msgpack_object` (in `msg.data`) invalid, once `msgpack_sbuffer_free(buffer)` is called?*

No since it is not related to the `sbuffer` (see above).

But it is invalid as soon as `msg` is destroyed, i.e. at the end of the `create_static_msg_object` function since `msg` is a local variable.

Note: within the above code you should take care to call `msgpack_unpacked_destroy(&msg)` so that the internal memory allocated while unpacking is properly freed. By doing so the msgpack object is also zeroed out.

*- What's the correct way to get a heap allocated `msgpack_object` with no dependencies?*

I would say you have 2 solutions:

1. Deep duplicate (most common case): browse the `msg.data` object recursively and duplicate each piece of data within your own heap allocated structure. Doing so is easier if you are unpacking an archive with an expected pre-defined format.
2. Maintain `msg` on memory: allocate your unpacked structure dynamically (`msgpack_unpacked *msg = malloc(sizeof(*msg));`), init it, unpack it and return it to the caller so that you can use the related object at your convenience. The caller must manage deletion: here again use `msgpack_unpacked_destroy` to free up the internal zone memory then free your `msg` pointer.